# Equivalence of different taylor expansion of the same identity

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I am trying to compute a second order Taylor expansion of the following identity: $x = yz$.
Where I get stucked is when I transformed the original expression into $y= \frac {x}{z}$, I simply get a different approximation due to the fact that the second order derivative with respect to $z$ in this second form is not zero while they are all equal to 0 in the first form.

What am I missing ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your setting, in $x=yz$, $y$ is a function in $z$, i.e. $y=y(z)$. So using the Leibnize's rule to calculate the derivatives gives that the fist order derivative of RHS is $$z\frac{dy}{dz}+y(z)$$ and now can you calculate the second order derivative of RHS?

Comment: I am still puzzled, here we therefore have  \begin{equation} z \frac{dy}{dz} + y(z) = z \left(- \frac{x}{z^{2}} \right) + y(z) = 0
\end{equation} , no?

Comment: @user2614750 Yes. In fact, I tried to explain your confusion in my answer. From $x=yz$ we have $$0=\frac{dx}{dz}=\frac{d(yz)}{dz}=z\frac{dy}{dz}+y$$ and then we calculate the second derivative:$$0=\frac{dy}{dz}+z\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}+\frac{dy}{dz}.$$ We must do the calculation in this way. So, the statement in your post that "while they are all equal to 0" is not right. What you missed has been well-explained above.